# Cron creating empty files in the root directory

Tags: cron

It creates files with 0 Bytes, with the same name as the php being called in the task.

I have a task that runs every minute, my folder /root is crowded.

My task:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q https://domain/script.php
```

**How to stop creating these files?**

Comment: What do you want to know? Is it how do I stop these 0 byte files? How does crone Work? How can I stop crone from producing 0byte files? Please expand your question so that it helps others in a similar situation and add the relevant question(s)

Comment: What is the result when you run `wget -q https://domain/script.php` in terminal? Do you get non 0 bytes file in this case?

Comment: @SimplySimon I want to know why, and how to disable.

Comment: OK, Add this information to your question. You will find that people will ignore your question, or vote it down if it doesn't have enough information in it. :)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I tested right now, it returns the same file.

Comment: @SimplySimon add :)

Comment: Click edit, under your question and add it there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why?**

Because this is what `wget` command is doing and because your cron job call `wget` at every minute. From `man wget`:

> GNU Wget is a free utility for **non-interactive** download of files from the Web.

It creates files with 0 bytes because probably `script.php` does not return nothing in non-interactive mode.

**How to stop creating these files?**

Run in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) next command to open the crontab file:

```
crontab -e
```

and delete or comment the line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q https://domain/script.php
```

Save the crontab file and close it.

Or just simple use:

```
crontab -r
```

to remove your crontab file.

If you want to make the cron job only to access `https://domain/script.php` every minute, then use `curl`, `ping` or maybe `lynx`. For example:

```
* * * * * curl https://domain/script.php
```

More about: http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/

Comment: With this solution I am without a job. I need the job, I just want to prevent the generation of these files.

Comment: @Ricardo For what you need the job? This is what your cron job is doing: download a file every minute from `https://domain/script.php`...

Comment: I need this page to be accessed by the minute. No need to download. Should I continue using wget?

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
wget -a /dev/null https://domain/script.php
```

This will discard the output altogether. The -q flag just stops wget log messages, not the actual output.